# For an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation, is there a method that would return all the conditions/scopes used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

This question applies for Rails 3.x

Let's say I have a Business model, and Company and City models...each Business belongs to a company and belongs to a City...and I have scopes set up so that:

```
City.businesses.owned_by(some_company_id)
```

...returns all businesses in that city, owned by some_company.

Is there a method that I can use at the end of that chain of scopes to return all the conditions used to return the relevant activerecords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `arel.constraints` or just `constraints` on the `ActiveRecord::Relation` you have access to the conditions array.

For example, in one of my applications I have a scope called `active`:

```
z = Auction.active.constraints.last
=> #<Arel::Nodes::Grouping:0x007fa66753c108 @expr="auctions.ending_at > '2011-08-22 23:44:11.591438'">
z.expr
=> "auctions.ending_at > '2011-08-22 23:44:14.295435'"
```